# How to properly code offset in a copy paste loop VBA

Tags: vba, copy, offset, paste

I'm trying to copy then paste into cells in a loop. Using cell BP3 as an original reference im trying to write it such that after each iteration it pastes into the next cell down from BP3 i.e BP4. But I currently just repeats in cell BP4.

```
' Copy and Paste of CAPEX 4 forecast dates from VR all DVs
Dim Updated_Spreadsheet As Workbook
Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = Workbooks("study tracker.xlsm")

Set Updated_Spreadsheet = Workbooks("VR.xlsm")
Set sht = Updated_Spreadsheet.Sheets("Variance Report")
Set sht2 = wb.Sheets("Environmental Studies")

'Loop
Dim cell As Range, lRow As Long, NextRow As Long, lngDataRows As Long
For Each cell In sht2.Range("A3", sht2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown))
  'specifying cell i want to use as a criteria for the filter
  'cell = sht2.Range("A3").Value
  sht.Activate

  'specifying filter range
  sht.Range("$A$7:$GV$4694").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=cell

  'specifying the exact cell from the filter which I would like to copy
  sht.UsedRange.SpecialCells _
    (xlCellTypeVisible).Areas(2).Columns(171).Cells(1, 1).Copy
  wb.Activate

  'pasting into new location
  lngDataRows = cell.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
  Range("BP3").Offset(lngDataRows + 1, 0).Select
  Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Next cell
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only getting cell "BP4" because every time your loop runs you're selecting the same cell over and over again.
Initiate a variable (before starting your loop) that will increase in value with each loop iteration.

```
OffsetBy = 1
'Your "For Each" loop starts here
'(...)
'Use this variable in here:
Range("BP3").Offset(lngDataRows + OffsetBy, 0).Select
OffsetBy = OffsetBy + 1
Next cell
```

Hope this helps!